# Make random dice array return unique attributres / prevent duplicates

Tags: jquery

i have this dice array that changes attribues(srcset) in grid gallery and i need it to show unique attribues until it runs out and than start again so i wont see 2,3,4 of the same image in grid.
Thanks for help

Heres the jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    //array
    var dice = $('.attachment-lenslight_squares').map(function() {
        return $(this).attr('srcset')
    }).get();

    $('.attachment-lenslight_squares')
        .click(function() {
            var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * dice.length);
            $(this).fadeOut(200, function() {
                $(this).attr('srcset', dice[num]);
            }).fadeIn(200);
        });

    setInterval(function() {
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15);
        $('.attachment-lenslight_squares').eq(rand).click();
    }, 3000);

});
```

Thanks for ideas

Comment: What about using an array and popping off each item as it's used? You're kinda doing that with `num` but I've done something very similar in PHP using arrays like this with good success.

Comment: One way of doing this is to generate an array of values, then using a shuffling algorithm to "randomize" them, then just just keep a pointer to the next value to return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can swap elements using `.not()`, destructuring assignment, `.html()`

```js
var items = $(".items").on("click", "div", function() {
  $(this).fadeOut(200, function() {
    var not = $.map($(".items div").not(this), function(el) {
      return $(el).index(".items div")
    });
    var next = not[Math.floor(Math.random() * not.length)];
    var index = $(this).index(".items div");
    var elems = $(">div", items).toArray();
    [elems[next], elems[index]] = [elems[index], elems[next]];
    items.html(elems).find(this).fadeIn(200)
  });
});

var interval = setInterval(function() {
  items.find("div")
    .eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * items.find("div").length))
    .click()
}, 3000)
```

```css
.items div {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 1px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="items">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is awesome! this is the exact behaviour i needed it completely prevetns duplicates but the animations are kinda weird, sometimes it fades out but not fades in and vice versa, do you know possible fix? Also while i have chance to ask (since i couldnt find any info) is it possible to have 2 or 3 different animations other than fadein/out cycling or randomly changing every time animation is used ? Thank a lot !

Comment: @MartinSprušanský _"sometimes it fades out but not fades in and vice versa"_ Can you create a jsfiddle to demonstrate? _"is it possible to have 2 or 3 different animations other than fadein/out cycling or randomly changing every time animation is used ?"_ Not certain what you mean by 2 to 3 different animations?

Comment: animations are visible whne i run your code here, the two that are swapping have not the same fadeout for some reason and so it looks incosistent, i put it in pen with loger fade times so its obvious whan i mean: http://codepen.io/nikenko/pen/PbRzwN

-the pari that is beiong swapped behaves like this: one fades out and just pops in and other just pops out and thand fades in, is it possible to have them both fadeout together and than fadein so it looks the same?

and by 2-3animatiopn i meant that if its possible to run animations in cycle like this: first animation fadein/out second toggle

Comment: @guest271214 and than again fade and than toggle

Comment: @guest271214 Thanks a lot :) awesome

Answer (score 0):

Create a dice number range randomly first; then pop from it.

```
function generateRandomDiceNumbers () {
    // return array of 6 numbers pushed randomly
}

function getRandomDiceRoll (diceNumbers) {
    // use diceNumbers.pop()
}
```

A simple implementation:

```
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  // from mdn
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

function getRandomDiceNumbers() {
  let numbers = [];
  while(numbers.length < 6){
    let r = Math.floor(getRandomArbitrary(1, 7));
    if(!numbers.includes(r)) {
      numbers.push(r);
    }
  }
  return numbers
}

var randomDiceNumbers = getRandomDiceNumbers();
function getNextRandomDiceNumber(numbers) {
  if(numbers.length > 0) {
    return numbers.pop();
  }
}

// use getNextRandomDiceNumber(randomDiceNumbers);
```

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    var dice = $('.attachment-lenslight_squares').map(function () {
        return $(this).attr('srcset')
    }).get();

    var used = [];

    function setNum() {
        var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * dice.length);
        if (used.includes(num)) {
           setNum(); // invokes itself if a used number is detected
        }
        used.push(num); // send new unused value to used array for next check

        $(this).fadeOut(200, function () {
            $(this).attr('srcset', dice[num]);
        }).fadeIn(200);
    };

    $('.attachment-lenslight_squares')
    .click(function () {
        setNum(); //set random number / invoke sequence on click
    });

    setInterval(function () {
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15);
        $('.attachment-lenslight_squares').eq(rand).click();
    }, 3000);
});
```

---

I haven't tested this, but.. you could basically just add a recursive check to your existing code.